# Convert RGB value to LONG and LONG to RGB JQuery

Tags: jquery, colors, rgb, long-integer, color-picker

I'm trying to convert RGB color value into Long and convert back that Long value to RGB. For example:

If I've RGB like this rgb(189,92,92), it should be converted to long integer and that converted long integer should be converted back to same R, G, B values(189,92,92).

How can I do that??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'converted to a long value'? JS has no 'long' datatype. I'm assuming you just want to get `189`, `92` and `92` as integer values from the string, right?

Comment: I want to convert these values to integer and convert back that integer to RGB.